# String to word break using C++

Tags: c++, string

i have written sample code to string to word convert, but not able to understand the reason why output coming as My only.
below help me out the reason why this is happening like this.

```
//g++  5.4.0
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

char abc[20] = "My name is abc";

char result[5][10]= {
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };
int k = 0,j=0;


for (int i =0; abc[i]!='\0'; i++,j++)
{


    result[k][j] = abc[i];
    if (abc[i] == ' ')
    {
     result[k][j] = '\0'; 
     cout<<result[k]<<endl;
     k++;
     j=0;


    }


}     
}
```

output of the below code is coming as My only not the next word after My.
result[k] (inside if condition) return only My not the next coming word.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you sure `j` has the value you expect when you get back to the top of the loop after finding a match?

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you step through the code, line by line, in a debugger while monitoring your variables, the problem should become very obvious.

Comment: @John3136 j is coming back to 0 once finding space.

Comment: take a look at the order of which the statements in the `for` are executed: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Answer (score 0):

there's `j++` every loop, so `j=0` is set to `j=1` in next loop.
This leads to `result[k][0] = 0` for every `k>0`.

And it is also need to deal `abc[i] = '\0'` case, otherwise last word don't appear.

```
for (int i =0; ; i++,j++) {
    result[k][j] = abc[i];
    if (abc[i] == ' ' || abc[i] == '\0') {
        result[k][j] = '\0';·
        cout<<result[k]<<endl;
        k++;
        j=-1;
    }

    if (abc[i] == '\0') break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
j = -1;
```

inside the if statement. Rest you can figure it out.